# Unusual behaviour in an OpenMP program

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a program and i tried to use **Open MP**.

The output is still correct (i tested it after multiple runs), but the times i get are quite odd.

So the time for the single threaded version is **0.1** seconds.

With **2** treads i get **0.05**, but with **4** i obtain **0.15** seconds.
How is this possible?

I am just using simple parallel for's.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
for(i = 1; i <= total_height; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= total_width; j++){
        int current_neighbours = neighbours[i][j];
        // if(i == 2 && j == 1)
            // printf("%d%d\n", current_neighbours, neighbours[2][1]);
        if(current_neighbours == 0 || current_neighbours == 1 || current_neighbours > 3){
            if(map[i][j] == 1){
                update_maps(i, j, 0);
            }
        }
        else if(current_neighbours == 3){
            if(map[i][j] == 0){
                update_maps(i, j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The update_maps functions looks like this

```
void update_maps(int i, int j, int value){
    map[i][j] = value;
    int k, neighbouri, neighbourj;
    int num_of_thread = omp_get_thread_num();
    if(value == 0)
        value = -1;

    for(k = 0; k < 8 ; k++){
        neighbouri = i + di[k];
        neighbourj = j + dj[k];
        if(in_map(neighbouri, neighbourj)){
            neighbouri--;
            neighbourj--;
            modify[neighbouri * total_height + neighbourj + (total_height * total_width * num_of_thread)] += value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

How many cores do you have? Do the threads access shared data regions/objects?

Comment: I updated the original post

Comment: Oh, and i have 4 cores, i even tested it on a cluster with 8 cores.

Comment: From the code you provided, I don't see immediate problems.  But it looks like the memory you need grows linearly with the number of threads; could that be an issue?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement the game of live, right?  Did you consider double buffering? Also, I would suggest to enforce a chunk-wise parallel distribution of iterators over threads (I don't know what the default is -- round robin would be bad for spacial data locality).

Comment: Yes, i am implementing game of life. And yes, the memory i need grows linearly with the number of threads. I did this to avoid locks and make the program faster. I do not understand clearly what are your suggestions. Do you mean i should change the scheduling?

Comment: I think static scheduling in chunks should be the best.  As for the memory: Exceeding the cache size might be a reason for the program becoming slower.

Comment: Ok, i used static scheduling. But it don't get different results.
And as for the memory, i had an earlier version of the program, where i just used one matrix for the current map, and creating another one to get the new map. After computing the new matrix, i just copied it in the old one. Still 4 threads work slower than 2.
(and i didn't use that much memory)

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.  One last thought: I'm wondering why you keep a neighbor count and not the population of each cell.  The latter would avoid write conflicts altogether.

Comment: How are you timing this (e.g. do you use Clock())? You normally should not have to use `omp_get_thread_num()`. This makes me think you made a poor choice in implementing your algorithm with OpenMP. Maybe you can post the scalar version.

Comment: i am timing it with bash's time functio